# Do scripts loaded with ocLazyLoad get cached by the browser?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browser, oclazyload

Sorry if this is a newbish question.

I'm using the ocLazyLoad plugin with AngularJS and UI Router. I am using ocLazyLoad with Ui router to dynamically load/lazy-load in my controllers based on the route that is hit in my webapp.

**My question is will these lazy-loaded scripts get cached by the browser? And if they are is there a way to force the browser to download a fresh copy (without turning off caching on my webserver).**

The problem I am trying to solve is this, I wish to serve up a new version of my index.html with an MD5 hash to force browsers to reload code every time a new version of the webapp is deployed. So if I load up a new index-1ab34c.html my concern is that the lazy loaded JS files will be the same old cached ones and not the fresh code that is deployed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question asked more than 100 times actually by different type of question, angular router has a cache problem, the basic solution for this problem is **version**.

Desktop or laptop has a option to hard refresh `ctrl + F5` this helps to reload all files from beginning, but devices like mobile or tablet doesn't have this option so you have to use **version** to handle this problem.

> Try to version all of your **requests** and **files**, this helps
>   application to get new files and request by last version.

**example:**

```
var version = "0.0.1"; //0.0.2 // 0.0.9 // 0.1.0 
//requests
$http.get("users?v=" + version).then(...);

//files
//loading with oclazyload or what you want no deference
"application/controller.js?v=" + version
```

Version is global variable because you will change it from one place every publish.

Comment: Interesting. I didnt know about the filename.js?v=xyz approach. I planned on adding a hash to the non lazyloaded files but in the file name. Example: app-a1de13.js. This solution you proposed I could try out too.

Comment: rename files will removed the cache and it's wrong way to manage browser cache but `version` will update files when they are changed.

Comment: Both versioned query and filename are correct ways to handle this and will work.

Comment: Sure, @estus is right about what he said, but change file name mean you want to version it, so instead rename it we will set version, it will easier and faster. thanks Mr.estus